# Cloudflare is not minifying my page (I've read the documentation)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cloudflare

I have reviewed the documentation thoroughly, verified the settings, cleared the cache, and have waited for changes to take effect.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/speed/optimization/content/troubleshooting/auto-minify-not-working/

I have a simple webpage. According to the documentation, there are three tools available for different types of assets, and my code meets the criteria for all three. However, Cloudflare is not minifying my page at all. What am I doing wrong?

Page: https://play.carimbo.cloud/0.0.47/carimbolabs/snake/0.0.13

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <base href="{{.BaseURL}}" />
  <link rel="preload" href="bundle.7z" as="fetch" type="application/octet-stream" crossorigin />
  <link rel="preload" href="carimbo.wasm" as="fetch" type="application/wasm" crossorigin />
  <title>Carimbo</title>
  <style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      line-height: 1.5;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #canvas {
      width: 854px;
      height: 480px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"></canvas>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

      var Module = {
        canvas,
        noInitialRun: true,
        onRuntimeInitialized: () => {
          fetch("bundle.7z")
            .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
            .then((data) => {
              const uint8View = new Uint8Array(data);
              FS.writeFile("/bundle.7z", uint8View);
              Module.callMain();
            });
        },
      };
    </script>
    <script src="carimbo.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Settings:

[image]

[image]